# Python Pandas: Shift two rows of DateTimeIndex by half an hour

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe using a DateTimeIndex in half hourly resolution. The data has an error in two timestamps where the hour value is wrong and needs to be shifted 1 hour back

The data is being read in from an excel sheet that the creator has confirmed as an error. Basically the first 03:00 and 03:30 timestamps should be shifted to 02:00 and 02:30

```
DateTime,Results
2014-11-05 01:00:00,135
2014-11-05 01:30:00,125
2014-11-05 03:00:00,158
2014-11-05 03:30:00,565
2014-11-05 03:00:00,684
2014-11-05 03:30:00,474
```

You can load the above using `df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=0, parse_dates=True, sep=',')`.

I have tried incorporating `df['2014-11-05 03:00:00'].shift(perfiods=1,freq='-60Min')` but not having much joy and not sure how best to proceed with this. It feels like this should be simple but hit a bit of a brick wall.

Comment: Can you just replace the wrong values with the right values?

Comment: I'd even do that in the Excel sheet itself if I were you...

Comment: I ended up doing this but from what I understand a lot of the data I will end up getting will have similar errors for some reason so wanted a way to cehck and modify it if it happens

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the argument, let's say you're in a case where don't know where that happens or cannot edit the source file. Here's a way you could do this:

```
In[1]: df = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=0, parse_dates=True, sep=',')
```

Now, we will convert the index to a `pd.Series` since `index` doesn't support item assignment.

We will use the `duplicated()` with the parameter `keep='last'`: the first occurences of something that appears more than once will be shifted by 60Min:

```
In [2]:
s = pd.Series(df.index)
s[s.duplicated(keep='last')] = s[s.duplicated(keep='last')] + pd.Timedelta('-60Min')
df.index = s
df

Out[2]:

                     Results
DateTime                    
2014-11-05 01:00:00      135
2014-11-05 01:30:00      125
2014-11-05 02:00:00      158
2014-11-05 02:30:00      565
2014-11-05 03:00:00      684
2014-11-05 03:30:00      474
```

The above would work fine assuming you don't get into a case where a timestamp will be repeated more than twice.

---

Another alternative is to completely overwrite the index using [`pd.date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) if you know for a fact that it's a constant 30Min interval:

```
df.index = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), periods=len(df), freq='30Min')
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.